# Concrete5 Superfish Navigation height (Bootstrap theme)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, concrete5

I have a little problem with Superfish navigation height in bootstrap theme.
-->testi4.aada.fi

I'm not able to reduce its height at all and there is this

```
element {
line-height: 113px;
}
```

if you check it with Firefox inspector and i do not know where it is coming from

Pls, help.

// Mika

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try using %'s instead?

i.e.

```
element {
   line-height: 90%;
}
```

If that doesnt work, try some additional padding/margin within that element.

```
element {
   line-height: 113px;
   padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: @Mika I'm glad it did! Can you accept the answer please!

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion..  You can play with the values using Firebug under Firefox to get the correct value/setting..